# what is better ... OCJA7 then OCJP7 or SCJP6 then upgrade to OCJP7?

Tags: java, scjp

I've decided to be java certified we all know that `OCJA7` or `OCJP6` are pre-request  for `OCJP7`

So I need to decide which cert are better to start with but I need to consider that there will be a gab between the first exam and second one about 4 months

Is to get `OCJP6` then upgrade it to `OCJP7` better or  to Start from `OCJA7` ?

Comment: In addition to not being objectively answerable, this question's subject matter is off topic.

Comment: As Stephen C said, answers to this questions are subjective. But I figured if you get enough subjective answers, that might help you to make a decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on your level of java knowledge and what you intend to do. I assume you are a software developer.

OCA (Oracle Certified Associate) is a really basic entry exam. From my experience in Germany, employees usually don't care about it.

OCJP (Oracle Certified Java Professional) shows that a developer has some knowledge of Java. Employees (again in Germany) actually know about and this certificate might help you to get a job offer. There are a lot of rather bizarre questions asked during OCJP, so it's a really good idea to study OCJP preparation materials.

Now, when it comes to versions, I think employees don't care too much about it. You could have OCJP6 or OCJP7 but that won't matter too much. Your actual work experience will count a lot more than the OCJP version. That said, having a really old OCJP certificate might not be perceived so well. Updating your OCJP certificate once in 3-5 years should be enough for the most employees.

Comment: Thanks so much Jzelenkov your answer are very helpful .... 
I'm software developer as you said and I'm targeting a J2EE job offer ... and you gave me the exactly answer I want " which cert comanies care about newest or more advanced :)"
I wish I could vote up your answer but I'm still below 15 rep :)

again thank you very much  .. once I get more than 15 rep I'll vote your ans up